# Add href data attribute to a div with target blank

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, custom-data-attribute

I an trying to apply href attribute on a div using data-attributes
since I can't use A tag in my case.
it works fine but I am trying to add another data attribute in order to open the link in target blank
here is my code

```
$('.artist-box').each(function(){
    var aTag = $(this).attr('href');

    $(this).attr('data-href',aTag);        

    $("[data-href]").click(function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).attr("data-href");
        return false;
    });
})
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window.open instead of window.location

```
$('.artist-box').each(function(){
    var aTag = $(this).attr('href');

    $(this).attr('data-href',aTag);        

    $("[data-href]").click(function() {
        window.open($(this).attr("data-href"),'_blank');
        return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: Great @plazm  Thx a lot